# What does the dot mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can someone explain the difference for these two CSS selectors?

```
.work-container . h3 {
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 0px;
font-weight: 600;
height: 27px;
}
```

What is the extra dot in the upper definition?

```
.work-container h3 {
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 0px;
font-weight: 600;
height: 27px;
}
```

Comment: The first example is not valid CSS. Probably a typo.

Comment: The CSS was given to me with a bunch of weird properties, and I'm not the css expert.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A `.` prefix usually represents a class selector, but if it's immediately followed by whitespace then it's a syntax error.

If I were to hazard a guess, then it's likely the author meant to say `.work-container > h3`, but missed the Shift key just as he was about to type the `>` character (the [child combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905)).

Your second selector, `.work-container h3`, simply means any `h3` that's contained within an element with a class called `work-container`.

Comment: To quickly check whether a style sheet has syntax errors, http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ is very handy. The error handling rules are defined in the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors and in this case they imply that the entire rule is ignored (but other parts of the style sheet are not affected).

Comment: @BoltClock, in CSS, I think you can also have a dot in-between something like div.ui-datepicker. How will you explain it?

Answer (score 98):

Cases

- Selector start with dot

`.class_name` signifies class name

- Two dotted selector separated by space

`.outside` `.inside`

means element with `.inside` class descended from an element with class `.outside`

- Two dotted selector without separation

`.name1.name2`

means element that has both class `name1` and `name2`
eg: `class="name1 name2"`

Related questions:

- [What does a space mean in a CSS selector? i.e. What is the difference between .classA.classB and .classA .classB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/what-does-a-space-mean-in-a-css-selector-i-e-what-is-the-difference-between-c)
- [What's the difference between CSS classes .foo.bar (without space) and .foo .bar (with space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036156/whats-the-difference-between-css-classes-foo-bar-without-space-and-foo-bar)

Comment: Thanks! I checked 4 online guides to CSS selectors and Eric Meyer's "CSS Pocket Reference" and could not find this distinction in any of them.

Answer (score 24):

`.` in CSS means it is a class and it can be applied to many elements.

`#` in CSS means it is an ID and it can be applied to one element per page.

Without the either, it is a tag, targets all the elements with the tag name.

In your syntax, `.work-container . h3` is actually error. The `.` should have been either `,` or as [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) said, `>`, which says the direct descendant operator in CSS.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the meaning of 'targeting all the usage' part please?

Comment: @muthuh Sorry I was super dumb back then. It targets to match the tag name. I hope it's clear. I have updated the answer too.

Answer (score 10):

`.` says its class

`#` means its an id

and if there is nothing but the selector, then it is a tag

Answer (score 7):

`.` in CSS means it is a class & it can be applied to many elements with use space between classes

For example:

```
<h3 class="class1 class2 class2">Heading</h3>
```

`#` in CSS means it is an ID and it can be applied to one element per page.

For example

```
<h3 id="idname1">Heading</h3>
```