# What is the purpose of command has-sub and align-center

Tags: css, alignment, symbols

I came across the following tag in CSS3. Being 'CSSmenu' div class name. I have problem in understanding the remaining syntax like :

why referred with dot(.)

## cssmenu.align-center

## cssmenu .has-sub

Comment: In css, dot refer to a class name. So it's selecting cssmenu with attribut class containing `align-center` or `has-sub`. The space between is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the dot mean in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811149/what-does-the-dot-mean-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

`.a` refers to **all the elements which has the class `a`**

`div.a` refers to **all div which has the class `a`**

`div .a` refers to **all children of a div which has the class `a`**

That's the same for your example :

`.cssmenu.align-center` refers to **all the elements which has the classes `cssmenu` AND `align-center`**

`.cssmenu .has-sub` refers to **all the elements which has the class `has-sub` and are children of an element which has the class `.cssmenu`**

Answer (score 1):

`.cssmenu.aligncenter` is used to select a div with multiple classes. That is, I want to select the `cssmenu` which has another class `align-center`.

`.cssmenu .has-sub` is used to select a div which has `.has-sub` nested within. Also known as Descendent selector.

```css
.cssmenu.aligncenter {
  text-align: center;
}
.cssmenu .hassub {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cssmenu">Not centered and not bold</div>
<div class="cssmenu aligncenter">Text centered</div>
<div class="cssmenu">
  <div class="hassub">It contains subsections, so I am Italic</div>
</div>
```