# Understanding CSS "section.positioned" Selector

Tags: html, css

Can some one explain the following css code I found in a web page and which element does the `section.positioned` affect?

```
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
```

Part of web page code

```
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    ......
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but does your question stem from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/)? If so, I created an updated version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/7442/) which should make things a little clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `section.positioned` rule target an element like this:

```
<section class="positioned">

</section>
```

By changing the existing html section element's class from empty to "positioned", the `section.positioned` rule will apply to the element instead of the `section` rule.

**Added:**

What `section.positioned` really means is it target an element of type "section" which has a class named "positioned".

Further reading about css selectors:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
- [What does the dot mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811149/what-does-the-dot-mean-in-css)