# r shiny bsCollapse has multiple panels open when multiple = FALSE

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I have been working with `shinyBS` to create a set of collapsible panels.  In the one shown below, only one panel should be open at a time (since the parameter `multiple` defaults to `FALSE`), but all three can be opened at the same time.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
      bsCollapse(
        id = "stuff.all", 
        bsCollapsePanel(title = "Load Data", "Load the files"),
        bsCollapsePanel(title = "Set Parameters", "Set the parameters"),
        bsCollapsePanel(title = "Teacher Settings", "Choose the teachers")
      )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

What is causing this `bsCollapse` to act as though `multiple = TRUE`, and how can I prevent it in the future?
Reference: https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Collapses.html

I actually figured this out while writing the question, so I plan to answer my own question.

Answer (score 4):

The `id` for `bsCollapse` in my example was "stuff.all".  The fact that a period was part of the `id` seems to be what created the problem.  When I changed the `id` to "stuff", the problem went away.  When the `id` is "stuff.al" or "stuff.a", the problem persists.  When the `id` is "stuff." or ".stuff", none of the panels expand when clicked.  Given the way that `bsCollapse` works, the problem arises either from having a period in the `id` of an HTML `<div>` tag like so:

```
<div class="panel-group sbs-panel-group" data-sbs-multi="FALSE" id="stuff.a" role="tablist">
```

or from having a period in the `data-toggle` of an HTML `<a>` tag, like so:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#cpanel0758223" data-parent="#stuff.a">Load Data</a>
```

Comment: This is related to the use of the dot operator in CSS.  Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811149/what-does-the-dot-mean-in-css