# Purpose of ".listsg" in a style tag

Tags: html, css

In [this HTML page](http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLibrary/getProjInfoNational.do?projId=0008aa9b6bb04b9180d4d9a597b020b4) there is the following text within the `<style>` tag:

`.listsg {` ... `}`

What is the purpose of `.listsg`? A Google search didn't turn up anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a HTML class used for CSS styling, the name of the class could be whatever you want. For example:

HTML:

```
<p class="listsg">Text</p> // this text will be in yellow color
```

And then you can style it in CSS:

```
.listsg {
    color: yellow;
}
```

I assume you thought "listsg" is a HTML tag. Here is more about classes and how they work: [HTML Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811149/what-does-the-dot-mean-in-css), `.` is a class selector. So `.listsg` selects the class "listsg".

If you look further in the document, notice a line `<div class="listsg" >`. The purpose of `.listsg {` ... `}` is to assign style attributes to this `div` block, based on the text in between the braces (i.e. `{` and `}`).