# CSS subclass with and without space

Tags: css, subclass

Sorry for this noob question. What is the difference between

.nav.left

and

.nav .left

in CSS

Comment: Have a read of the [Selectors Level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/); I think it'll answer this, and many other, questions. As well as, quite possibly, raising several others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10036181/1164179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.nav .left means your are targeting .left within the .nav element like

```
<div class="nav><div class="left"></div></div>
```

Where as .nav.left means both classes are on the same element like

```
<div class="nav left"><div></div></div>
```

A quick google would have probably found you and answer to this, try taking a read of w3c schools its a good place to start http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Just to be pedantic, w3schools is not affiliated with the W3C.

Comment: Very true updated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Different between

`.nav.left` ---> e.g. `<div class="nav left"></div>` two class in same div.

and

`.nav .left` ----> e.g. `<div class="nav"><div class="left"></div></div>` one .nav div is parent div and .left div is child