# Issue with setting a style

Tags: css

I have a dropdown list using a `<select>` element. For where I place this dropdown list on the page, I only want that page's list affected by a style so I give a class of 'posts' on the select element.

In my style sheet, I have:

```
.posts select
{
  margin-left: 40px
}
```

It does not work UNLESS I remove the .post. Why?

Here's the element:

```
<select class="form-control posts" (change)="reloadPosts({ userId: u.value })" #u>
       <option value="">Select a user...</option>
       <option *ngFor="#user of users" value="{{ user.id }}">
            {{ user.name }}
       </option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Do like this `select.posts` instead

Comment: Are you looking for `select.posts` instead of `.posts select` ?

Comment: may be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036156/whats-the-difference-between-css-classes-foo-bar-without-space-and-foo-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.posts select` target a `select` being a child of an element having the class `.posts`

HTML Sample where `.posts select` work

```css
div {
  background: lightblue;
}

.posts select {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
  <select>
    <option>Select a value</option>
  </select>
</div
```

---

In your case you should do like this, `select.posts`, which target a `select` having the class `posts`

Do note, there should be no space between `select` and `.posts`

HTML Sample where `select.posts` work

```css
div {
  background: lightblue;
}

select.posts {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select class="posts">
    <option>Select a value</option>
  </select>
</div
```